# How to add a line break in a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a line break in the following code:

```
$('.carlo_txt p').text(senior.p1_desc   + '  ' + senior.p2_desc)
```

it is in the script.js and it fetches data from a .json file.

```
"p1_desc": "A line",
"p2_desc": "Another line",
```

I want to add a line break between the two lines.
I tried `<br/>` and `\n` but they did not work.
Please help.
I don't really know how to code. I am just a beginner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br>` and call the `html()` function, not `text()`

```js
const senior = {'p1_desc': 'A line', 'p2_desc': 'Another line'}

$('.carlo_txt p').html(senior.p1_desc   + '<br>' + senior.p2_desc)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='carlo_txt'>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It did not work. The senior.json file is of the format `{
   "p1_desc": "1st line.",
    "p2_desc": " 2nd line",
}`

Comment: and the script.js is `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.senior-link').click(function () {
        name = $(this).text().toLowerCase()
        $.getJSON('example.com' + name + '/senior.json', function (senior) {
            document.title = 'Farewell to' + senior.name;
            document.querySelectorAll(".name").forEach(name => {
                name.innerHTML = senior.name;
            });
            $('.carlo_txt p').text(senior.p1_desc + '  ' + senior.p2_desc)`